# Is it possible to retrieve a specific BattlePet given a name and a realm via the Warcraft API?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battlenet-api

I'm trying to retrieve a specific World of Warcraft Battle Pet's info given its name.  Blizzard provide a [pretty handy API](http://blizzard.github.io/api-wow-docs/#battlepet-api) for such things but I can't see how I'd find a specifically named Battle Pet, given a realm name etc.

I can pull down an array of all of a specific Character's Battle Pets but I want to find the data for a pet that's not part of a specific character's collection.